Windows Product Key registry value is null in C#
Here is the code
RegistryKey ProductKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\SoftwareProtectionPlatform");
labelKey.Text = "Product key: " + ProductKey.GetValue("BackupProductKeyDefault").ToString();

What I'm trying to do is to get value of my Windows Product Key through the respective registry key for my WinForms applicaton. However, it does not return the key, instead it says that value is null.
The key path and value name are correct, I checked that around five times. Elevating to administrator through UAC doesn't work as well. Where did I make mistake?
